# Delay webview creation

Tags: cordova

My iOS app uses PhoneGap 2.9, and I'd like to add the capability upon app start to check my server for updates to the www assets and download any such updates before creating the web view.

My question is: What do I do in code to delay the creation of the web view until the update check and/or download are complete, and then create that web view when the update is ready?

Comment: I figured it out. Basically, I should move the boilerplate code in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function which creates the MainViewController/CDVViewController to the place where I'm ready to load the web view.

One side effect is that the splash screen is not displayed, because apparently it's rendered by the CDVViewController/CSVSplashScreen. Should I just create a separate view for splash screen, or is there a simpler way without re-inventing the wheel? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically, I edited CDVViewController.m, and cut out the code at the end of viewDidLoad in the acquireLock which loads the request. I moved that code to the point in the workflow where I'm ready to load it, i.e., after checking/downloading any updates.